# Python: handling a large string value - if statement not working properly?

Tags: python, string, if-statement, byte

I have this large string value, about 500 characters called 'strPage6'
I'm looking to see if nth position of this string has the '%' value with an if statement without success.

```
#see if 330th character has value '%'
if (strPage6[330:331]=="%"):
   print("330th character is '%' ")
   print(strPage6)
else:
   print("330th character is NOT '%' ")
   print(strPage6)
```

my terminal returns the following value:

```
330th character is NOT '%'
b'%'
```

I tried switching the byte string into a plain string with 'decode' with the following result:

```
strPage6=strPage.decode('utf-8')
[...]

330th character is NOT '%'
e
```

Basically, I am looking to get the following result:

```
330th character is '%'
%
```

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: why the slice til 331, just try and get back 330th position from the list...`strPage6[330]`

Comment: Did you try `strPage6[330]==b"%"`?

Comment: you said `strPage6` has 500 chars but `print(strPage6)` shows only one char. Check `len(strPage6)` - maybe your `strPage6` doesn't have 500 chars.

Comment: as furas says. it seems your string is not 500 characters long. However to be really sure I suggest to use `print(repr(strPage6))` instead of `print(strPage6)`

It should help you to display any potentially hidden characters, but my bet is the string is not what you expect it to be.

Perhaps show the exact code that populates `strPage6`

Comment: please be absolutely sure, that the code that you put in the question is really the code, that you execute. The smallest difference between the code, that you execute and the code that you post makes it almost impossible for others to help you.

Please add also following code:
`print("type of strpage6 =", type(strPage6))` and also `print("len strpage6 =", len(strPage6))` and also `print("strpage6[320:340] = ", repr(strPage6[320:240]))`
one of these prints will hopefully explain what's going on

Comment: @kelwood it returns what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: @user3078293 Can you address what gelonida wrote? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @AMC for the sake of simplicity I had to trim it down to this, it is part of a long code on Django on my views directory, basically there's a pattern in pdf files I'm reading (with PyPDF2), and need to examine if the nth character is a special character; hence determining if it's version A or verson B of the pdf in question. I'll keep your advice in mind! I'm still a beginner playing around, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try strPage6[330]==b"%"? – khelwood

does the equation properly